# How to change the shape of an image using PHP and imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagemap

I need to manipulate images on the server-side via PHP. I use ImageMagick for that purpose, and there are a lot of great functions, but no documentation...

The issue is the next:

- I have two images a png with a transparent background, and a jpg one;
- I need to change the JPG image that has the same shape as the visible part of the PNG.

I don't want to crop the image, but to adjust to the PNG's visible part. Is that possible to do?

Example:
[image]

[image]

Comment: There is actually a lot of documentation with examples, although I will admit that they use a lot of words that are more mathematical than common. I think you are looking for distort: https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.distortimage.php

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I've read this one, but there you need to add 16 points x,y for the start and end position of each corner. But, I need a solution for cases when I don't know these points, just have a PNG image, and I need to fit my JPEG image by its visible shape.

Comment: This is where things start to get crazy, I think you are looking for [polynomial distortion](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/distorts/#polynomial). You will need to classify your shapes. Things with straight edges should be fairly easy, but things with curves will probably need to be manually accounted for (or through AI). You'll have to start with shape detection to determine the edges of your input mask. Good luck with this!

Comment: Okay, this sounds promising. Thank you very much.